# Flutter Local Notifications for Ios

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I want to receive notifications using the flutter_local_notifications package. I can't receive notifications on iOS devices while notifications are coming on Android devices. My code is like this:

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

const String darwinNotificationCategoryPlain = 'plainCategory';

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  NotificationHandler.showNotification(message);
}

class NotificationHandler {
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  static final NotificationHandler _singleton = NotificationHandler._internal();
  factory NotificationHandler() {
    return _singleton;
  }
NotificationHandler._internal();

initializeFCMNotification(BuildContext context) async {
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings('online_bekci_icon');
  final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
  DarwinInitializationSettings(
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
  InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: selectNotification);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    showNotification(message);
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    showNotification(message);
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}

static void showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
  AndroidNotificationDetails('1234', 'Yeni Mesaj',
    channelDescription: 'Arti Guvenlik Notification',
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
    ticker: 'ticker');
  const DarwinNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails = 
DarwinNotificationDetails(/*categoryIdentifier: darwinNotificationCategoryPlain*/);
  const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
  NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iOS: iosNotificationDetails);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0, message.notification!.title, message.notification!.body,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: 'Aktarılan Değer');
 }

void selectNotification(NotificationResponse payload) async {
if (payload.payload != null) {
  debugPrint('notification payload: ${payload.payload}');
}
}

void onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
  int? id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) {}
}
```

My AppDelegate.swift file looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import flutter_local_notifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
}
```

I had previously used this package in a different project and it was working correctly. But when I used it then, I was working with IOSNotificationDetails method instead of DarwinNotificationDetails. I'm using this method now that it's obsolete. But for some reason I am not getting any notification with this code. Thanks in advance for your help.